# Make images mobile-responsive in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, iphone, image, responsive

I know it's a few threads about this, but none of them is working for me and that's the reason why I'm asking for YOUR help. Well. I'm creating a website, and I'm trying to make my images responsive but I can't get it to work.

```
#banner2 {
background-image: url(Images/banner2.jpeg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
max-width: 100%;
height: 500px;
max-height: 50%; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #banner2 {
        background-image: url(Images/banner2.jpeg);
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

This is my CSS code so far, and I've tried in a lot of ways but I can't really get it to work on my Iphone.

I've also added this line of code in the HTML.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But still no..

So when I'm trying to open the webpage on my iPhone, the image doesn't look how I would like.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into using boostrap?  It makes this VERY easy to do!

Comment: Since we don't know how you would like the image to display, please try to explain your desired outcome and how the actual result differs from that.

Comment: @JadeFisher "Just use Bootstrap!" is not a real solution.

Comment: @JadeFisher I'm using bootstrap, but that dosent fix the images.. Only the rest of the page, hehe.

Comment: @Turnip This is how I want it, and this is also how it looks like on the PC screen. (I'm using background-attachment: fixed to get parallex scrolling) 
How I want: https://gyazo.com/ad9ebd2d3f21be5b78df97b969fea101 And this is how it looks like on the Iphone: https://gyazo.com/b1cce0ffe9e658d17463da42dc086d50

Comment: @LolPrezy Can you edit this code pen to show the issue your having? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXdEXE

Comment: Any reason you are using a background image?  If it has to be a background image, then for the height, use the [padding top trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) to create an aspect ratio - at the moment, height auto will probably mean your div has no height and therefore it won't show

Comment: You all can try it with https://www.annanbok.se/

Comment: @Pete Well, bascially I'm using it because it is a "background" image. I linked the page of the website so you can see / try it out. But I don't really know if It has to be a background image or not. The point is to let the background attachment do it's job. But I guess you can use parallax scrolling with non-background images aswell.

Comment: @LolPrezy the code for the images is not wrong there is something else capping your page width at 411 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using background-image, you can use `padding-bottom` to force the element to maintain it's aspect ratio as it resizes.

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-image: url(path/to/img.jpg);
}
```

You will have to tweak padding-bottom to achieve the desired aspect ratio.